# Using ValidationTextBox in Dojo with maxlength high hangs the entire UI

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am using ValidationTextBox in Dojo which has the maxlength as 180, now when I quickly type all the character at once it hangs the entire UI.

E.g. keep the character "p" on your keyboard pressed contiguously on validation text box the entire browser hangs.

This happens in all the browsers.

Comment: What other properties and events are on the textbox? A pared down example with simple maxLength works http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/NXHbv/

Comment: I am using the declarative way..<input type="text" id="saveServiceName" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([a-zA-Z0-9-_])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*$', maxLength: 160, invalidMessage: 'Only Alpha-Numeric Characters with - and _ allowed.Starting and ending must be alpha-numeric characters'" ></input>

Comment: Well I was able to reproduce it in my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/NXHbv/).  Oddly enough it only seems to affect the declarative version with that regex.

Comment: Weird, I'm not having any problems on IE or Google Chrome on Windows or on Chromium, Firefox or Opera on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it better to move programmatic way, I am not sure which way to proceed.

Comment: in html body i added :<td  class="cellWidget"> <div id="saveServiceName"></div></td> and added in script body as shown below:require(['dijit/form/ValidationTextBox', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (TextBox) {
    var textBox = new TextBox({
        regExp: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([a-zA-Z0-9-_])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*$',
        maxLength: 160,
        invalidMessage: 'Only Alpha-Numeric Characters with - and _ allowed.Starting and ending must be alpha-numeric characters'
    });
    textBox.placeAt('saveServiceName');
    textBox.startup();
 });

Comment: in html body i added :<td  class="cellWidget"> <div id="saveServiceName"></div></td> and added in script body as shown below:require(['dijit/form/ValidationTextBox', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (TextBox) {
    var textBox = new TextBox({
        regExp: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([a-zA-Z0-9-_])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*$',
        maxLength: 160,
        invalidMessage: 'Only Alpha-Numeric Characters with - and _ allowed.Starting and ending must be alpha-numeric characters'
    });
    textBox.placeAt('saveServiceName');
    textBox.startup();
 }); however i am not able to access dijit.byId("saveServiceName")

Comment: if i access in the above way it says undefined.

Comment: Any update on this? Would love to see a programmatic solution

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maxLength attribute directly in the widget creation

or

```
myValidationTextbox.set('maxLength', 4)
```

I agree with you that setting it via **constraints** as an alias makes sense if 
you have multiple different validation widgets.

So I think you have discovered a *bug* and the dojo people always encourage you to file a bug for each issue. You can do that here:
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org